# SQL Sum with Group By Math Expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

I have made this query with a kind of math expression but the result is not what I expected.

The query is:

```
select
   c.nome,
   coalesce(b.montante * :nMeses, 0),
   coalesce(sum(d.montante), 0),
   coalesce(round((sum(d.montante) / (b.montante*:nMeses))*100, 0), 0) 
from
   budget b 
   join
      categoria c 
      on c.id = b.categoria_id 
   left join
      dado d 
      on d.categoria_id = c.id 
group by
   c.nome,
   b.montante
```

The result is:

| nome | column | column | column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alimentação e Bebidas | 500 | 1370 | 274 |
| Alimentação e Bebidas | 100 | 1370 | 1370 |
| Casa e Serviços | 286 | 100 | 35 |
| Compras | 180 | 150 | 83 |

The problem is that I want to group by only by the first column and sum the rest but somehow I can't because it gives me this error:

> "SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "d.montante" must appear in the
> GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i don't think i understood...

Comment: well I missed there are two type of `montante` columns `b.montante` (alredy listed next to GROUP BY), and `d.montante`. Indeed you shouldn't get such an error message then. Are you sure about the current query.

Comment: can `d.montante` has a different value than `b.montante`?

Comment: Yes it can. d stands for expense and b stands for budget, they are different things

Comment: You say you want to group only by `c.nome` and sum the rest, but you don't sum `b.montante*:nMeses`, so `b.montante` must be in the GROUP BY clause in this case. If you put `coalesce(sum(b.montante * :nMeses), 0)`in the `SELECT` clause, then you can remove `b.montante` from the `GROUP BY` clause.